# Object from class in other class to access UIView iOS Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, view, hidden

`ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"classA" bundle:nil];`
                                                         `a.viewInClassA.hidden = NO;`

**When i Run this code, the a.viewInClassA.hidden = NO do not make any effect PLEASE HELP**

Comment: Is `a.viewInClassA` is bydefault hidden ? and outlets are connected or if created programmactically it is added to view `a` ?

Comment: Yes hidden in storyBoard , and outlet is connected.

Comment: What is the value of alpha property of this view ?

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewInClassA;

Comment: @JigneshMayani please put an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is happen because you are making new class you not taking reference. So make property of that class and pass reference of class c in another class and then you can do hide using that property

In   ClassA for example you have  tableview.

Put this in ClassA.h file

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;`

From classB.h file make property of classA

`@property (Strong, nonatomic) classA *classAObject;`

And form classb.m where you want to hide table view write this

```
self.classAObject.tableview.hidden = YES;
```

when you open classB pass classA reference

```
ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB" bundle:nil];
classB.classAObject = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:classB animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and manipulate another view controllers views. It's a violation of the principle of encapsulation.  It's bad design, and sometimes it fails, as in your case.

Instead, add a property to your ClassA view controller that tells whether or not your view should be hidden. In your ClassA view controller's viewWillAppear read the property and use it to hide or show the view.